# Android ComputableFuture doesn't work with Firestore

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore, completable-future

I am trying to use `CompletableFutures` with **Firestore** in **Android**. I have set up a function utilizing `CompletableFutures` as seen below:

```
CompletableFuture<List<Park>> loadAllParks(){
  final CompletableFuture<List<Park>> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
  db.collection("parks")
    .get()
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                List<Park> results = new ArrayList<>();
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult())) {
                    Log.d("SUCCESS", document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                    Park documentObj = document.toObject(Park.class);
                    results.add(documentObj);
                }
                future.complete(results);
            } else {
                Log.d("ERROR", "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                future.completeExceptionally(new CustomExceptions("Firebase Error"));
            }
        }
    });
  return future;
}
```

and this function is called in the following manner:

```
try {
    allParks = loadAllParks().get();
    for (Park park: allParks) {
        Log.d("DEBUG", park.getName());
    }
} catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "An error has occurred while retrieving the parks.",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

However, this results in an error of:

> W/Firestore: (21.4.1) [OnlineStateTracker]: Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds
>
> This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will > operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.

Thus, I've instead tried it out without the `CompletableFuture` functions in the following maner, and was able to get the desired output with the following code:

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
db.collection("parks")
  .get()
  .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            List<Park> results = new ArrayList<>();
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult())) {
                Log.d("SUCCESS", document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                Park documentObj = document.toObject(Park.class);
                results.add(documentObj);
            }
            for (Park park: results) {
                Log.d("DEBUG", park.getName());
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("ERROR", "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
        }
    }
  });
```

As such, it is pretty obvious to me that for some reason, the `CompletableFuture` is not completed, and it somehow causes the **Firestore** call to not get through (and hence unable to connect to Firestore). I would appreciate any advice on why this is the case!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, I switched to `.getNow()` instead of `.get()` and the result is obtained successfully. Not sure why, because from the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#getNow-T-) it seems like the only difference was with `.getNow()` you could supply a default result. Any explanation is welcome!